# Should the Kalman Gain and error covariance matrices be diagonal?

Tags: matrix, kalman-filter

I have developed an extended Kalman filter and initialize the Kalman gain matrix, the previous, current and next state error covariance matrices to a diagonal of 1's. After the first sample the matrices are no longer diagonal. Is this correct or should they remain diagonal?

Comment: Answer on Cross Validated about the positive semi-definiteness of error covariance matrices: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56832/is-every-covariance-matrix-positive-definite

Answer (score 3):

The covariance matrix (typically called P) is an estimate of the errors in your state. The diagonal elements are the variances of you state variables. The off-diagonal elements indicate the correlations between the (errors/uncertainties in) your state variables.

You will typically initialize P by setting the diagonal elements to the uncertainty in your initial values of the state (in most cases quite large), The measurements will bring the uncertainties down when running the filter and in almost all but the trivial cases, the off diagonal elements will become nonezero.

Note that P should be symmetric and stay symmetric.

Comment: When do the correlations happen?

Comment: You observe it when you write out the KF equations, e.g. for propagation: x=Ax+w, P=APA^T + Q. Example: for a KF estimating position and velocity A = {{1,T^2},{0,1}}. If you apply the propagation of P, you observe that off-diagonal elements in P are now nonzero.

Comment: so that means I don't have control over them? In other words, what will happen if I set them as zeros? Or just I should apply the equations and that's it?

Comment: You can set the off-diagonal to zero initially, but after that, you do not touch them. In the propagation they grow larger. After a measurement, they get smaller. For the case of the simple 2 state position-velocity filter described above, the off diagonal matrix element makes sure that if you have a velocity measurment, also the position is corrected. If you set them to zero, this is will not be the case. So, the covariance matrix 'knows' how much error in one state has caused errors in the other states.

Comment: I have a similar problem. My matrix P is not symmetric. I don't know how to debug the problem :(

Comment: The P matrix should not get asymmetric. This is likely an implementation bug or caused by numerical inaccuracies. First thing I would try is find out if the asymmetry occurs first after the propagation (time update) or correction (measurement update). 
You could start a new question on SO.